# Find a recurrence relation for $a_{n,k}$ , the number of ways to order n doughnuts from k different types of doughnuts if

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find a recurrence relation for $a_{n,k}$ , the number of ways to order n doughnuts from k different types of doughnuts if two or four or six doughnuts must be chosen of each type.

I need help understanding the answer to this.

So I know the answer to this is

$a_{n,k}=a_{n-2,k-1} + a_{n-4,k-1}+a_{n-6,k-1}$

so I know that $a_{n-2,k-1}$ means you start by picking $2$ donuts of one type, then you pick the remaining $n-2$ donuts from the other $k-1$ types

$a_{n-4,k-1}$ means you start by picking $4$ donuts of one type, then you pick the remaining $n-4$ donuts from the other $k-1$ types

$a_{n-6,k-1}$ means you start by picking $6$ donuts of one type, then you pick the remaining $n-6$ donuts from the other $k-1$ types

But how does this satisfy the constraint that two or four or six doughnuts must be chosen of each type? That's what I'm confused by. Can't you just pick *any* amount of each type of donut from the other $k-1$ types, not just two or four or six.

If someone can explain this to me, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $a_{n,k}$ requires 2, 4, or 6 donuts of *each* of the $k$ types.  The recurrence relation is just splitting up the possibilities according to the number of donuts of type $k$.  Once you have decided whether that is 2, 4, or 6, you have a smaller problem with fewer donuts and only $k-1$ types of donuts.  The constraint on number of donuts of each type still applies to $a_{n-2,k-1}$, and $a_{n-4,k-1}$, and $a_{n-6,k-1}$.  If the constraints applied only to type $k$, the recurrence would instead be
\begin{align}
a_{n,k} &= b_{n-2,k-1} + b_{n-4,k-1} + b_{n-6,k-1} \\
b_{n,k-1} &= \sum_{j=1}^n b_{n-j,k-2} 
\end{align}
where $b_{n,k}$ is the (unconstrained) number of ways to order $n$ donuts of $k$ types.

Note: as a sanity check, you should find that $a_{n,k}=0$ when $n$ is odd.